# what is the versions of javax.json-api and javax.json which support JDK 17

Tags: dependencies, java-17

I have to convert my original java program (which was written for jdk 11) to jdk 17. In build.gradle file it has following dependencies.

```
implementation group: 'javax.json', name: 'javax.json-api', version: '1.1.4'  
implementation group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.json', version: '1.1.4'
```

Therefore I need to find javax.json-api and javax.json versions which support for JDK 17.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and used jakarta

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/jakarta.json
implementation group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'jakarta.json', version: '2.0.1'
```